# Determining if two given matrices in the symplectic Lie group $Sp(2)$?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

Define the following quaternionic matrices $1=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, i=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}, j=\pmatrix{0&-i\\-i&0}, k=\pmatrix{i&0\\0&-i}$

I am given that the symplectic group is the group of linear transformations preserving the inner product in $\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{R^4}$. I want to know if $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{j&k\\k&j}$ and $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&i}$ are in the symplectic lie group $Sp(2)$?

My problem is that the definition is not clear enough to me, so this is difficult to think about. Any ideas out there?

Comment: By the inner product you mean the dot product? (Or the quaternion multiplication?) What does "preserve" mean?

Comment: @Wauzl, I mean dot product, also preserve means the properties of dot product hold, or are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to check if this two matrices preserve inner product of $\mathbb{H}^2=\mathbb{C}^4=\mathbb{R}^8$. So the simplest way is using those quaternionic matrices to get 4*4 matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ and check whether they are unitary.

Here is a detailed process of calculating inner product: the first matrix send $(u,v)\in\mathbb{H}^2$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(ju+kv,ku+jv)$ and:

$||(ju+kv,ku+jv)||^2=(ju+kv)^{*}(ju+kv)+(ku+jv)^{*}(ku+jv)=-(u^{*}j+v^{*}k)(ju+kv)-(u^{*}k+v^{*}j)(ku+jv)=u^{*}u+v^{*}v-u^{*}iv+v^{*}iu+u^{*}u+v^{*}v+u^{*}iv-v^{*}iu=2(u^{*}u+v^{*}v)$

put back the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ we get correct result.